# HTML & JQuery: Silde page on top of another

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to one page to slide on top of another page. When Page slides, another page in background is faded out. Like on [this](http://www.mckinsey.com/) site. When you click on McKinsey overview button, that visible strip of html is added to the page that slides and page in background go disabled. Also it looks like page that slides is pre-loaded.

I tried several page slider jquery plugin but is not the same as in link mentioned above. The don't disable the page in background. Also when they hide, they hide the entire page. But i want some visible part of it available to user. Kindly guide me.

Comment: You don't need a plugin for this.  Just learn jQuery `.animate()` and load your content when animation is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "homeSlider" class is [available for review on the site](http://www.mckinsey.com/global_resources/dotcom/js/home.js) (search for MC.homeSlider) It animates opacity and margin-right.

imho its easier to toggleClass between an "#slider" and "#slider.open" and using css transitions for the animation.

Code to accomplish this looks like this:

// jquery

```
$("#sliderBtn").click(function(){
    $("#slider").toggleClass("open");
});
```

// css

```
#slider {position:absolute;opacity:0;margin-left:300px;transition: opacity 2s, margin-left 1s;}
#slider.open {opacity:1;margin-left:100px}
```

Of course the downfall is that older browsers do not get to see the animation. It degrades properly though by showing an opened and closed state appropriately.

jsbin: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rhudB